# Bootstrap Nav Pill updating two different Divs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a webpage which will look like this:

```
-------------------------
| top banner             |
-------------------------
| nav-pill menu          |
-------------------------
| content area           |
|                        |
-------------------------
```

To navigate I am using Bootstrap Pills. I would like nav-pill menu buttons to change **both** top banner and content area.

My code so far:
**Top banner:**

```
<div class="tab-content">  
<div id="menu1a" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <span>Test 1</span>
</div>
<div id="menu2a" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <span>Test 2</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Pills:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="display: inline-block;">
<li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="pill" role="button" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="pill" role="button" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
</li>
<ul>
```

**Content area**

```
<div class="tab-content">  
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in">
     <span>Test 1</span>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in">
    <span>Test 2</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Essentially my question is: is it possible to call two separate IDs from `<a data-toggle="pill" role="button" href="#menu1">` nav button in the menu?

I have tried using `onclick="href='#menu1'; href='#menu1a'"` as well as JQuery

```
 $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#menu1a").addClass("active");
    $("#menu1").addClass("active");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that having two elements with the same id is not a correct practice in html and can cause unexpected problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `href` you can use `data-target` that targets a common class that is shared by all the elements you want to toggle with your anchors. Also add the active class to the tab-panes that you want to show by default.

**Bootply**
http://www.bootply.com/2LgV53lYVi

**Markup**

```
<div class="tab-content">  
  <div id="menu1a" class="tab-pane fade in menu1tab active">
       <span>Test 1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2a" class="tab-pane fade in menu2tab">
      <span>Test 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="display: inline-block;">
  <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="pill" role="button" data-target=".menu1tab">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a data-toggle="pill" role="button" data-target=".menu2tab">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">  
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in menu1tab active">
       <span>Test 1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in menu2tab">
      <span>Test 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```